Data not fetching from smart contract for the same code in different versions of "ethers"
I am trying to make a dApp for real estate marketplace. I was using "ethers" 5.7.2. Everything was perfectly fine. In the various categories screen, the properties data of various properties were returnign perfectly from the smart contract and displaying in the appropriate pages like "Housing", "Rentals" etc available in the Home screen.
//FETCH CONTRACT
const FETCH_CONTRACT = (PROVIDER) =>
  new ethers.Contract(REAL_ESTATE_ADDRESS, REAL_ESTATE_ABI, PROVIDER);

//CONNECTING WITH CONTRACT
const connectingWithSmartContract = async () => {
  try {
    const web3modal = new Web3Modal();
    const connection = await web3modal.connect();
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
    const PROVIDER = provider.getSigner();

    const contract = FETCH_CONTRACT(PROVIDER);

    return contract;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

Now, for a screen, I am trying to use the BrowserProvider. So I upgraded my ethers to 6.8.0. Now, the page where the properties data stored in the smart contract is supposed to return and display, I am getting empty things in console.log:

But when I am using the 5.7.2 ethers version, I am getting this in console.log:

The "components" part of the data returned in both the cases seem to be different. Is the error something related to it? (PS: Im new to web3)
In v5

In v6

How to fix this error? I want to continue with v6. How to make sure that the property data is returned properly from the smart contract and that its not empty?
Links for reference:
1) Repository link - https://github.com/ahkharsha/briXchange-Test
2) store.tsx (Where browser provider is used) - https://github.com/ahkharsha/briXchange-Test/blob/main/client/PageComponents/Components/GardenComponents/store.tsx

Since you’re using ethers v5, so it should be Web3Provider instead of BrowserProvider, and you’ve to remove await, as in v5, provider.getSigner() doesn’t return a Promise of signer, instead returns the signer object directly.
So, replace:
const signer = await new BrowserProvider(window.ethereum).getSigner();

with:
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();


For ethers v6, you can use BrowserProvider from ethers directly (like ethers.BrowserProvider), but in that case, while fetching the signer using provider.getSigner(), you need to use await, as it returns the Promise of the signer:
const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
const signer = await provider.getSigner();


Hi, I have updated the question stating the entire problem from the beginning

Okay. But, do you want to use v5 or v6, as you can’t use both in a single project?

I’ve edited my answer to add the syntax for ethers v6 as well. Please check.

I want to continue with v6. I replaced
const web3modal = new Web3Modal();     const connection = await web3modal.connect();     const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);     const PROVIDER = provider.getSigner(); with your code const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum); const signer = await provider.getSigner();.
But it is still returning empty data

Okay, but as per your use-case, you need to use connection instead of window.ethereum, as you were doing in your code snippet. The syntax that I shared is just for reference.

Let me know if you still face the same problem. Then, I’ll clone your repo and debug on my end.

I tried that too earlier. But its still not displaying.

And, are you facing that for all the networks listed in your context/constants.js?

Or, I think,  you've only built it for Polygon Amoy as of now.

Can you please guide me how to navigate through the app, in order to show the logs that you've attached in your screenshot?

Yea, I have built it for polygon amoy as of now. The smart contract is deployed in amoy testnet

So once you reach the home page,you will be able to see various categories of property properties.If you click on "Housing" in the homepage,it is supposed to list all the housing properties listed for sale (when a property is listed for sale, it is given a unique index number which is then used to list these properties). This is working correctly and the properties are being listed correctly when I use ethers v5, but nothing is being listed when v6
So the flow is Home > Housing.
If you see the console log after coming to this page, you'll see exactly similar to the screenshot I attached

Got it. Actually, you've to replace all the presence of Web3Provider with BrowserProvider and add await in the provider.getSigner() accordingly. And, there are repeated calls to wallet_addEthereumChain which is causing the unnecessary repeated pop-ups of MetaMask, resulting in the resetting of the network's state on every refresh and visiting to new page, therefore it's unable to connect to the contract. So, you have to sort out this issue first and clean the project in order to segregate the web3 connection at one place instead of creating providers and signers on every page.

Thank you for your explanation so far. I have 3 questions tho.

Why is it working and listing perfectly when I use ethers v5, and these problems only occur in v6.
The only place I have used Web3Provider is in my client/context/index.js, and I already replace it with ethers.BrowserProvider(connection) when you mentioned it in your answer above.
What does "segregating the web3 connection at one place" mean?

If you could explain these, it would be really helpful. Im pretty new to this domain ^^"


Can you create a separate branch in the same repo, with the ethers v5 implementation, so that I can test that too? 2) Is it popping-up metamask again and again, on your end too, for approving (even when you used ethers v5)? Because I think that could be one of the contributing factors to the issue. 3) Means to have the wallet connect and network adding/switching feature at one place, possibly in the navigation bar component, so as to avoid the reinitialization on every other page and just maintaining the connected account’s context. You can refer to how other dApps are doing that.



Yeap I have created a separate branch called "v5" with ethers v5. The property listings are working perfectly in it. You can check it out. I have not changed even a single line of code in it, just downgraded ethers version from latest to 5.7.2
Yea, it is asking over and over again when I am in some other chain other than polygon matic, and it is happening in both v5 and v6. Despite it happening, v5 seems to be working perfectly
Thank you


By the way, I've just checked by running your v5 branch, but it's also showing empty arrays in the console.

Oh is it so? I dont know, when I try using v5, I am getting the data correctly like what I have attached the screenshot in my post -
https://i.sstatic.net/UDvPmFVE.png

Yeah, I think the application got quite cluttered. I would suggest you to approach it in a modularized way, basically by creating a separate dummy app just having the wallet connect feature and fetching those arrays from the smart contract on some button click. In this way, it would be easy to break it down and then integrate the same into the full application.
